# deploying meteor on my own domain (ubuntu)

Tags: node.js, linode, javascript, meteor

I want to deploy my meteor app on my Ubuntu server, 
I used `meteor.sh` and everything went successfully, But i simply can't launch my app from the browser

I'm putting my ip address and getting a 404
`The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

I have apache2 running, and i removed its redirection to 8080 (i used it to tomcat before)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit confusing. Meteor uses default port 3000 if you don't specify differently. You don't need an extra webserver like apache since meteor comes with nodejs which does act as a webserver.

This is a simplified way you should start a meteor app on your machine

1. Install meteor
2. Create the project
3. Copy your files into that project
4. Start meteor in the folder you have your files
5. point your browser to http:/your.host:3000/

a more sophisticated way would be to use meteorite, create a dedicated user and write a startupscript.

see https://npmjs.org/package/meteorite

Comment: this is not good for production mode. that's why i used meteor.sh. The  problem with meteoric.sh is that your code should be on git.